# UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier called twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I have this code, and every time that I'm using it, the `viewDidLoad` of the destination view is called twice.

why it's happening?

```
Destination *myDestination = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"destination "];
MyCustomSegue *segue = [[MyCustomSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"CustomSegue" source:self  destination : myDestination];
[segue perform];
```

Comment: Why not just call performSegueWithIdentifier?

Comment: becuase I dont want to add a segue in the storyboard. but your answer helped me to understand that something in my custom segue is wrong.

Comment: Why don't you present view controller instead of creating segue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by calling method `presentViewController: animated: completion:;`
e.g

```
Destination *myDestination = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"destination "];
[self presentViewController:myDestination animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I hope this will help you out.